# Have the errors in "HDL Chip Design" by Douglas Smith ever been corrected?

Tags: verilog

My copy of "HDL Chip Design" by Douglas Smith is the ninth printing, July 2001.

The book systematically makes the error of using blocking assignments for synchronous communication, which results in nondeterministic code. Non-blocking assignments should be used in this case.

Has this ever been fixed in a later printing, if any?

Comment: So I guess not :-) http://www.sigasi.com/content/pitfalls-for-circuit-girls

Comment: It's usually best to just toss the old Verilog books in the waste bin.  Verilog is like C++, you need "Stroustrup" (Thomas & Moorby) as well as "Scott Meyers" (Stuart Sutherland) before anything under the hood really starts to make much sense.  :)  (And I do like Verilog, I'm not trying to make trouble here!)

Comment: @Dr.Watson Ok, but this book still often recommended, especially for practical Verilog design. Moreover, Thomas & Moorby 5th edition is almost as old, and has its own bunch of errors :-)

Answer (score 2):

I performed an extensive search on this just now and was able to find many printings but no new editions of the title.  Sorry!